# Send mailer Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, sendmail

I use Symfony2. My Action send a message and then redirect to a page.

Like this

```
public function myAction()
{
    ...
    some code 
    ...

    sendMessageWithSwiftMailer()
    ....

    return $this->redirect(Url);

}
```

This code work. But `Url` takes so much time to be opened. 
How can I first open the `Url` page and then send the message?
Can anyone give me any idea?

Comment: You have to set up a "worker" - have the email set up in a table of some sort with a cron running a console command to Symfony which processes emails. Then instead of sending a message when a user does an action, it just creates the database entry which "queues" the message. The cron would be set to something like every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
swiftmailer:
    spool: { type: file }
```

in your `config_prod.yml` and:

```
swiftmailer:
    spool: { type: memory }
```

in your `config.yml`.

Then, in production environment, you can create a crontab job which executes this Symfony2 command:

```
app/console swiftmailer:spool:send
```

This command will send your spooled messages.

More info at [symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html)